# Timertask change TextView setText()?

Tags: android

I'm trying use a Timertask to change a setText() of a TextView. I want change the text of TextView to each 10 seconds.

How can I do it ?

I'm trying this.

```
    private void clockTask(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                int count = 0;
                textViewPontuacao.setText(String.valueOf(count += 10));
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 100, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: What is happening with your current code?

Comment: I solved the problem, inside `run()` I added `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {}` and now works !